# mi primer proyecto de android

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo en ANDROID STUDIO, y quiero saber porque el main aparece en color naranja? (supongo que es un error); pero que debo hacer para que se corriga? en los videos donde empiezo a usar android studio no me dice nada relacionado a eso.

Comment: No es un error, solo esta resaltando la linea actual donde estas editando

Comment: tal como te mencionan solo esta resaltado la linea donde te posiciones o estas editando no es un error..!!

Comment: Vale, gracias :D